# quick sorting an array of structs using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, quicksort

My assignment is preforming quick sort on array of structs using pointers to the first and last elements of the array. This is the struct-

```
typedef struct Bus {
int number, distance, time; } Bus;
```

At some point of the program, i have an array of user-defined number of these struct. My goal is to sort the array by the time (lowest to highest). The functions that i need to fill are-

```
void swap(Bus *a, Bus *b)    
void quick_sort (Bus *start, Bus *end) 
Bus *partition (Bus *start, Bus *end)
```

that's my implementation-

```
void swap(Bus *a, Bus *b)
{
  Bus tmp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = tmp;
}

void quick_sort (Bus *start, Bus *end)
{
  long long n = end - start;
  if (n > 2)
  {
    Bus * pivot = partition (start, end);
    quick_sort (start, (end-1));
    quick_sort ((start+1), end);
  }

}

Bus *partition (Bus *start, Bus *end)
{
  long long n = end - start;
  int pivot = (end -1)->time;
  int i = start->time;
  int j = (end - 1)->time;
  for(;;)
  {
    
  }
}
```

I got this far and didn't knew how to continue. I will appreciate your help.

edit- Thats how i call the function from main- `quick_sort(arr, (arr + num_of_lines))` when num_of_lines is the size of the array.

Comment: Is this an exercise? Because if not, there's already `qsort`, though too comfortable to use either...

Comment: @WhozCraig `n = end - start` rather hints to pointing one past the array...

Comment: @Aconcagua yes this is an exercise.

Comment: You select your pivot at the very end – which results in an quadratic runtime if the array is sorted! Better: Choose a random element instead! But you shouldn't remember it's time, instead a pointer to the bus. How would you otherwise want to be able to return the pivot? Similarly `i` and `j` should be pointers to `Bus`.

Comment: @Aconcagua i have to select the last element as pivot, that's how i need to implement the algorithm

Comment: Ah, I see... So Lomuto (see @WhozCraig 's answer) enforced by the question – with problem of quadratic runtime on already sorted arrays, see link there. Well, you still could get around that by choosing a random element (or the Sedgewick approach, see link, too) and swapping that one to the end of the array. But that's a bonus only you provide...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your `quick_sort` is wrong. It should look like this:

```
void quick_sort(Bus *start, Bus *end)
{
    long long n = end - start;
    if (n >= 2)
    {
        Bus *pivot = partition(start, end);
        quick_sort(start, pivot++);
        quick_sort(pivot, end);
    }
}
```

Note the length condition. you should only skip partitions of length 0 or 1, not 2. And note the post-increment adjustment to the pivot index in the first recursive call. This ensures the subsequent recursion does *not* include the one element you do not want to include in the recursion: the pivot indexed value.

As far as the partition function is concerned, also wrong. It should look like this (I'm assuming you're using the [Lomuto Partition Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme):

```
int *partition(Bus *beg, Bus *end)
{
    long len = end - beg;
    if (len < 2)
        return beg;

    Bus *last = end-1;
    Bus *pvt = beg;
    for (;beg != last; ++beg)
    {
        if (beg->time < last->time)
            swap(pvt++, beg);
    }    
    swap(pvt, last);

    return pvt;
}
```